# Sabre REST API connection to Microsoft Powerapps Custom connector

Tags: oauth, powerapps, sabre

I am considering using Powerapps as a front end to Sabre.  I believe that the no code/low code approach is a potentially useful replacement for the Sabre scripts product in the travel agency community

Has anyone tried creating a customer connector in Powerapps that will connect to the Sabre API's using the Postman collections that Sabre has provided.

I am struggling with the OAuth 2.0 parameters for the connection.
[Powerapps OAuth parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oughy.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated
Michael

Comment: Please be more specific and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See the document that I attached to the request.  How do I match the required Oauth 2.0 fields that Microsoft is requesting with the Sabre REST API credentials.  I have the client ID and secret but it is not clear to me what the Authorization, Token, and Refresh URL's are

Answer (score 0):

Our small CTD operation is struggling with our conversion from SABREScribe to Web development too. My hats off to you if you get this working as we also have a few Power Apps but not connecting to SABRE. I'd be surprised if you can get this working and then how you show the value to the agent desktop. Curious as to your vision. I realize this is not the platform for general discussion but thought I'd just voice this as our Travel tech world is pretty "small"